# Kernel-power CRITICAL on Event Viewer led to PC Shutdown everytime

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, kernel, event-viewer

So i checked my event viewer on why does my PC shuts down by itself,

before shutdown theres a "bbzzzzzzz" sound, its like a sound lags. Then all my display freezes, after a few second, my PC restarts.

I've checked my harddisk health, and its alright. My PSU is alot higher than what my pc needed. so not because of power. MY CPU is kinda old though. I always open my HWMonitor software to keep an eye on the temperature, and everything is normal (under 65 celcius)

**Here's my hardware:**
[image]

I dont know what's wrong with my PC, but its sure disturbed on my work alot, I need all the help i can get.

[image]

Thankyou !!

Comment: You're mixing up cause and effect. The Event Viewer entry is merely recording that the PC shut down unexpectedly, after the fact. However, if you look in the vicinity, you may find other entries with more useful information.

Answer (score 0):

First, update ALL your drivers.  Get the manufacturer's Driver Update app and update everything.

Second, get the manufacturer's Hardware Diagnostics app and run that. Look for hardware errors. The tests should include all components including the power supply.

Second (a), get memtest86.exe  (https://www.memtest86.com/) put on a USB key and run 2 or 3 passes of memory for memory hardware errors.

Third, enable Minidumps (Advanced System Properties) and on the next crash, post the minidump as an edit to your question.

Thanks for trying all that.

Comment: I will try that thanks !